# How to split by an unknown number of tabs, spaces, and newlines in Rust?

Tags: rust

I want to achieve something very similar to `strings.Fields` in Go where I get all the non `\t` , `space` and `\n` consecutive character in a line

For example

```
this is a \n special \t\t word
```

will return

```
[this, is, a, special, word]
```

Is that possible in Rust?

The `split` function only takes an explicit pattern.

For example

```
a \t\t\t b \t\t\t\t c
```

with

```
for s in line.split("\t\t\t") {
    println!("{}", s);
}
```

will return

```
a
b
\t
c
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [`split_whitespace`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.split_whitespace) method defined on `str` in the standard library will do what you want.

The example from the documentation is pretty clear:

```
let mut iter = " Mary   had\ta\u{2009}little  \n\t lamb".split_whitespace();
assert_eq!(Some("Mary"), iter.next());
assert_eq!(Some("had"), iter.next());
assert_eq!(Some("a"), iter.next());
assert_eq!(Some("little"), iter.next());
assert_eq!(Some("lamb"), iter.next());

assert_eq!(None, iter.next());
```